# Gridview sorting up/down arrow in column headers

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, sorting, gridview, paging

I'm currently working on some code which is taking care of sorting and paging data in a gridview.  I'm now trying to implement sorting arrow (up/down arrows next to column headers) but I have no success.  The code to implement the sorting arrows is located in the *GridView1_RowCreated* sub routine. Right now, when I run the code, I don't see the sorting arrows at all. The problematic line is the following one: "If tblAdministrators.SortExpression = lnk.CommandArgument Then" I can't figure out what's wrong with that line.  It's always *False* therefore the arrows don't show up.

```
Private Function GetData(sort As SortDirection) As Data.DataView

    Dim connection As OracleDBConnect = DAL.GetOracleDBConnection()
    Dim request As OracleDBRequest = Nothing
    Dim result As OracleDBResult = Nothing
    Dim trace As OracleDBChronoTrace = Nothing
    Dim status As DBStatus
    Dim sb As New StringBuilder
    Dim dv As DataView

    With sb
        .Append("SELECT * FROM USERS")
    End With

    request = New OracleDBRequest(sb.ToString, CommandType.Text)

    status = connection.Execute(request, result, trace)

    dv = New DataView(result.DataSet.Tables(0))

    If (ViewState("sortExp") IsNot Nothing) Then
        dv = New Data.DataView(result.DataSet.Tables(0))

        If (GridViewSortDirection = SortDirection.Ascending) Then
            GridViewSortDirection = SortDirection.Descending
            dv.Sort = CType(ViewState("sortExp").ToString() & DESCENDING, String)
        Else
            GridViewSortDirection = SortDirection.Ascending
            dv.Sort = CType(ViewState("sortExp").ToString() & ASCENDING, String)
        End If
    Else
        dv = result.DataSet.Tables(0).DefaultView
    End If

    Return dv

End Function


Public Property GridViewSortDirection() As SortDirection
    Get
        If ViewState("sortDir") Is Nothing Then
            ViewState("sortDir") = SortDirection.Ascending
        End If

        Return CType(ViewState("sortDir"), SortDirection)
    End Get

    Set(ByVal value As SortDirection)
        ViewState("sortDir") = value
    End Set

End Property


Protected Sub GridView1_PageIndexChanging(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewPageEventArgs) Handles tblAdministrators.PageIndexChanging

    tblAdministrators.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex
    GridViewSortDirection = If(GridViewSortDirection = SortDirection.Descending, SortDirection.Ascending, SortDirection.Descending)
    tblAdministrators.DataSource = GetData(GridViewSortDirection)
    tblAdministrators.DataBind()

End Sub


Protected Sub GridView1_Sorting(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewSortEventArgs) Handles tblAdministrators.Sorting

    ViewState("sortExp") = e.SortExpression
    tblAdministrators.DataSource = GetData(GridViewSortDirection)
    tblAdministrators.DataBind()

End Sub

Protected Sub GridView1_RowCreated(sender As Object, e As GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles tblAdministrators.RowCreated
    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.Header Then
        For Each tc As TableCell In e.Row.Cells
            If tc.HasControls() Then

                Dim lnk As LinkButton = DirectCast(tc.Controls(0), LinkButton)
                If lnk IsNot Nothing Then

                    Dim img As New System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image()

                    img.ImageUrl = "/images/" & (If(GridViewSortDirection = SortDirection.Ascending, "asc", "desc")) & ".gif"

                    If tblAdministrators.SortExpression = lnk.CommandArgument Then

                        tc.Controls.Add(New LiteralControl(" "))
                        tc.Controls.Add(img)

                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

ASPX code:

```
 <asp:GridView ID="tblAdministrators" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" EmptyDataText="No records found" PageSize="25" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" OnRowCreated="GridView1_RowCreated">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Name" DataField="Name" SortExpression="NAME"></asp:BoundField>
        </Columns>
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="City" DataField="City" SortExpression="CITY"></asp:BoundField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at my sample:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" 
    AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="CustomerId" 
    DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle CssClass="sortasc" />
    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle CssClass="sortdesc" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="CustomerId" HeaderText="CustomerId" 
            InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="CustomerId" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="IdNumber" HeaderText="IdNumber" 
            SortExpression="IdNumber" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Pay attention on SortedAscendingHeaderStyle and SortedDescendingHeaderStyle. Just create apropriate css classes with background image (arrow up and arrow down) and you are done.

Comment: Gregor. That will only work when using an SQLDataSource which is not my case.  It would be really great if it would work since it's so easy to implement.

Comment: This is just a sample DataSource. It should work on any other datasource type too.

Comment: The "DataSourceID" is mandatory in order to use those functions (SortedAscendingHeaderStyle etc...) In my code, I'm not using a data source control but I'm rather doing a manual databinding.

Comment: @GregorPrimar: OP must be using a version of asp.net lesser than 4.0

Comment: On mine the arrow icon always shows on top of the header text. How may I force it to display a bit to the right of the termination of the text?

Answer (score 0):

In Order to add a sorting arrow in a Data Grid on a VB.net Windows Form, you don't even have to write any code

1. On form in Design Mode - select the grid you are working with, right click go to properties, set Selection Mode = Cell Select
2. On form in Design Mode - click the arrow on the grid on the right up, to edit column properties, select edit or add columns, set SortMode = Automatic
3. If you have code for your cell content (say you want user to open another form while clicking on any row in the data grid) then use CellDoubleClick property to handle the event. If the you have used single click then it will sort the header and also open the form for the given cell

Private Sub _CellDoubleClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DGAcctGrpList.CellDoubleClick